# Do you usually need a comma before "in this case"?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Example sentence:

> This was the first time she played the main character in a film---the movie of her life(,) in this case.

Do I need the comma in this case?

Note: I made a Google [search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22of%20life%20in%20this%20case%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN9bWOzs_XAhXGx7wKHcWUChIQ_AUIDigA&biw=1855&bih=990). But since Google omits punctuation, I couldn't find a very satisfactory answer.

Comment: I would rather put "in this case" at the start of a phrase, not at the end. For example: "This was the first time she played the main character in a film, in this case the movie of her life."

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

If you were going to include 'in this case' you would write:

This was the first time she played the main character in a film, the movie of her life, in this case.

But to the point, 'in this case' doesn't sound correct here and isn't needed at all. So:

***This was the first time she played the main character in a film, the movie of her life.***

Comment: I think the dash in the original works better than the comma in your first rewrite. Moreover, your second rewrite doesn't seem "to the point" at all. The question is asking about whether or not the comment should be included, not whether the sentence should be rewritten.

Comment: @J.R.actually it is "the point", as in, my viewpoint :) It is always a good idea to help people in multiple ways, not just answer their question and ignore a glaring error. Agree about the dash though, although both are "correct" grammatically.